# Pretty print Boto EC2 output from AWS

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

How do you pretty print Boto EC2 output from AWS?

Here's the original (not very pretty):

> {u'Reservations': [{u'OwnerId': '123456789012', u'ReservationId':
>   'r-0583ea9691fc65d99', u'Groups': [], u'Instances': [{u'Monitoring':
>   {u'State': 'disabled'}, u'PublicDnsName':
>   'ec2-52-91-153-194.compute-1.amazonaws.com', u'State': {u'Code': 16,
>   u'Name': 'running'}, u'EbsOptimized': False, u'LaunchTime':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 13, 14, 2, 13, tzinfo=tzutc()),
>   u'PublicIpAddress': '52.91.153.194', u'PrivateIpAddress': '10.0.0.50',
>   u'ProductCodes': [], u'VpcId': 'vpc-f06bb096',
>   u'StateTransitionReason': '', u'InstanceId': 'i-00b54d7f43d6d6c41',
>   u'ImageId': 'ami-f4cc1de2', u'PrivateDnsName':
>   'ip-10-0-0-50.ec2.internal', u'KeyName': 'ec2-test',
>   u'SecurityGroups': [{u'GroupName': 'default', u'GroupId':
>   'sg-d91a11a4'}], u'ClientToken': '', u'SubnetId': 'subnet-983e31a4',
>   u'InstanceType': 't2.micro', u'NetworkInterfaces': [{u'Status':
>   'in-use', u'MacAddress': '06:25:23:48:95:a6', u'SourceDestCheck':
>   True, u'VpcId': 'vpc-f06bb096', u'Description': '', u'Association':
>   {u'PublicIp': '52.91.153.194', u'PublicDnsName':
>   'ec2-52-91-153-194.compute-1.amazonaws.com', u'IpOwnerId': 'amazon'},
>   u'NetworkInterfaceId': 'eni-7813e976', u'PrivateIpAddresses':
>   [{u'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-10-0-0-50.ec2.internal', u'Association':
>   {u'PublicIp': '52.91.153.194', u'PublicDnsName':
>   'ec2-52-91-153-194.compute-1.amazonaws.com', u'IpOwnerId': 'amazon'},
>   u'Primary': True, u'PrivateIpAddress': '10.0.0.50'}],
>   u'PrivateDnsName': 'ip-10-0-0-50.ec2.internal', u'Attachment':
>   {u'Status': 'attached', u'DeviceIndex': 0, u'DeleteOnTermination':
>   True, u'AttachmentId': 'eni-attach-1497b932', u'AttachTime':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 13, 14, 2, 13, tzinfo=tzutc())}, u'Groups':
>   [{u'GroupName': 'default', u'GroupId': 'sg-d91a11a4'}], u'SubnetId':
>   'subnet-983e31a4', u'OwnerId': '123456789012', u'PrivateIpAddress':
>   '10.0.0.50'}], u'SourceDestCheck': True, u'Placement': {u'Tenancy':
>   'default', u'GroupName': '', u'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1a'},
>   u'Hypervisor': 'xen', u'BlockDeviceMappings': [{u'DeviceName':
>   '/dev/sda1', u'Ebs': {u'Status': 'attached', u'DeleteOnTermination':
>   True, u'VolumeId': 'vol-0bde7c66b5d2bfbe3', u'AttachTime':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 13, 14, 2, 14, tzinfo=tzutc())}}],
>   u'Architecture': 'x86_64', u'RootDeviceType': 'ebs',
>   u'RootDeviceName': '/dev/sda1', u'VirtualizationType': 'hvm',
>   u'AmiLaunchIndex': 0}]}, {u'OwnerId': '123456789012',
>   u'ReservationId': 'r-045b809e272d93e2b', u'Groups': [], u'Instances':
>   [{u'Monitoring': {u'State': 'disabled'}, u'PublicDnsName': '',
>   u'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', u'State': {u'Code': 48, u'Name':
>   'terminated'}, u'EbsOptimized': False, u'LaunchTime':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 13, 12, 56, 12, tzinfo=tzutc()),
>   u'ProductCodes': [], u'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated
>   (2017-04-13 13:57:36 GMT)', u'InstanceId': 'i-0c474bd415597945d',
>   u'ImageId': 'ami-f4cc1de2', u'PrivateDnsName': '', u'KeyName':
>   'ec2-test', u'SecurityGroups': [], u'ClientToken': '',
>   u'InstanceType': 't2.micro', u'NetworkInterfaces': [], u'Placement':
>   {u'Tenancy': 'default', u'GroupName': '', u'AvailabilityZone':
>   'us-east-1a'}, u'Hypervisor': 'xen', u'BlockDeviceMappings': [],
>   u'Architecture': 'x86_64', u'StateReason': {u'Message':
>   'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown', u'Code':
>   'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown'}, u'RootDeviceName': '/dev/sda1',
>   u'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', u'AmiLaunchIndex': 1}, {u'Monitoring':
>   {u'State': 'disabled'}, u'PublicDnsName': '', u'RootDeviceType':
>   'ebs', u'State': {u'Code': 48, u'Name': 'terminated'},
>   u'EbsOptimized': False, u'LaunchTime': datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 13,
>   12, 56, 12, tzinfo=tzutc()), u'ProductCodes': [],
>   u'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated (2017-04-13 13:57:36 GMT)',
>   u'InstanceId': 'i-08a8961ce06801f38', u'ImageId': 'ami-f4cc1de2',
>   u'PrivateDnsName': '', u'KeyName': 'ec2-test', u'SecurityGroups': [],
>   u'ClientToken': '', u'InstanceType': 't2.micro', u'NetworkInterfaces':
>   [], u'Placement': {u'Tenancy': 'default', u'GroupName': '',
>   u'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1a'}, u'Hypervisor': 'xen',
>   u'BlockDeviceMappings': [], u'Architecture': 'x86_64', u'StateReason':
>   {u'Message': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown',
>   u'Code': 'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown'}, u'RootDeviceName':
>   '/dev/sda1', u'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', u'AmiLaunchIndex': 2},
>   {u'Monitoring': {u'State': 'disabled'}, u'PublicDnsName': '',
>   u'RootDeviceType': 'ebs', u'State': {u'Code': 48, u'Name':
>   'terminated'}, u'EbsOptimized': False, u'LaunchTime':
>   datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 13, 12, 56, 12, tzinfo=tzutc()),
>   u'ProductCodes': [], u'StateTransitionReason': 'User initiated
>   (2017-04-13 13:57:36 GMT)', u'InstanceId': 'i-0912694d25b7c2d4f',
>   u'ImageId': 'ami-f4cc1de2', u'PrivateDnsName': '', u'KeyName':
>   'ec2-test', u'SecurityGroups': [], u'ClientToken': '',
>   u'InstanceType': 't2.micro', u'NetworkInterfaces': [], u'Placement':
>   {u'Tenancy': 'default', u'GroupName': '', u'AvailabilityZone':
>   'us-east-1a'}, u'Hypervisor': 'xen', u'BlockDeviceMappings': [],
>   u'Architecture': 'x86_64', u'StateReason': {u'Message':
>   'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown: User initiated shutdown', u'Code':
>   'Client.UserInitiatedShutdown'}, u'RootDeviceName': '/dev/sda1',
>   u'VirtualizationType': 'hvm', u'AmiLaunchIndex': 0}]}],
>   'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
>   'RequestId': 'f698802c-3506-49f5-8bc6-d40639e1e12c', 'HTTPHeaders':
>   {'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'server':
>   'AmazonEC2', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Thu,
>   13 Apr 2017 14:04:51 GMT'}}}

What are all those `u`s?

If I try using Python's JSON dump I get:

```
TypeError: datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 13, 14, 2, 13, tzinfo=tzutc()) is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module:

```
from pprint import pprint
pprint(your_data)
```

The 'u' prefix means that this is a unicode string.

Comment: Neat answer. Any way to get rid of the `u`s? Very distracting. And very inconvenient when you want to copy and paste.

Comment: Switching to Python 3.x would be the simplest way to get rid of the u's since in Python 3 everything is treated as unicode so the u prefix is not necessary any more.